# How do I use uploaded images from primary MSM site on other site?

Tags: multi-site-manager

I have a primary domain on a server then a secondary domain also on the same server. Using MSM, I setup the secondary site and things seem to be running smoothly except one thing.

The second site primarily mirrors the first site's content but with a different look/feel. I'm using channel entries from the primary site on the secondary site in some cases but have some issues with image assets.

I've found that in some cases I can use the site1.com's assets by just using the absolute url. But, if the image was uploaded within a field, there isn't the ability to just put "http://site1.com..." in front of the image.

Is there any sort of automatic way to have my image url's on site2.com point towards the folder on site1.com?

If it helps, I'm using Media Temple (gs) for hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done this using symlinks on the server filesystem.

If you'd like to post some details about the server path to the site root on for both sites along with some paths for images I can give a more detailed solution.

Comment: I actually figured this out using this method. Thanks for the offer though!